# Too many warnings on a C macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, warnings

I'm trying an approach to flag warnings on my code, but I did some mistake and can't understand where. My compiler gives me too much warnings about each use of this macro:

```
#define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

#define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

Example of use:

```
MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Test %d", 2);
```

```
 

    In file included from ../trunk/mpl_position.h:5:0,
                     from ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.h:6,
                     from ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp:1:
    ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp: In member function ‘int MPL_BaseEnvironment::getEnemyRobotAt(MPL_Position&, int)’:
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp:28:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("(invalid value) not in [0,%d) ", i_ER, qlMPLP_enemyRobot__.size());
             ^
    ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp: In member function ‘int MPL_BaseEnvironment::deleteEnemyRobotAt(int)’:
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp:45:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("(invalid value) not in [0,%d) ", i_ER, qlMPLP_enemyRobot__.size());
             ^
    ../trunk/mpl_baseenvironment.cpp: In member function ‘int MPL_BaseEnvironment::getMovableObstacleAt(MPL_Position&, int)’:
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__
```

EDIT: UPDATED Warnings list

```
    ../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h: In member function ‘long int MPL_GridEnvironment::arrayIndex(MPL_Position&)’:
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘,’ in format [-Wformat=]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h:253:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);
             ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘,’ in format [-Wformat=]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h:253:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);
             ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘)’ in format [-Wformat=]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h:253:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);
             ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:7:167: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(output, fmt, ...) fprintf(output, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " fmt "  ---\n\n"), __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__); //error message
                                                                                                                                                                           ^
    ../trunk/mpl_utils.h:9:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2’
     #define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);
                                         ^
    ../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h:253:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE’
             MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);
```

EDIT 2: as was requested, one of the places that triggers warnings:

```
inline long arrayIndex(MPL_Position& sMPLP_p)
{
    long x, y, z;
    x = MPL_ROUND_INT((d_delta*sMPLP_p.getX())/d_sizeX__);
    y = MPL_ROUND_INT((d_delta*sMPLP_p.getY())/d_sizeY__);
    z = MPL_ROUND_INT((d_delta*sMPLP_p.getZ())/d_sizeZ__);

    if( (x>=0) && (x<n_sizeX__) && (y>=0) && (y<n_sizeY__) && (z>=0) && (z<n_sizeZ__) ){ //isValidPosition(...)
        return( (x*n_sizeY__ + y)*n_sizeZ__ + z );
    }

    MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);

    MPL_GE_InvalidPosition(sMPLP_p);

    return( -1 );
}
```

(n_size?__ and d_size?__ are class attributes; dont bother trying to understand that... :P )

Comment: what are those warnings, please?

Comment: I tried to post them here, but I couldn't format them... I dont know how to paste them in a legible state. 
Are there some tags that let raw data be posted?

Comment: You could use `<pre>` and `</pre>` for that kind of text.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need to terminate preprocessor statements like C++ statements, you don't need the trailing semi-colon.

Comment: Those are not errors, those are *warnings*, telling you that you provide more arguments to `fprintf` than there are formatting codes.

Comment: `"(invalid value) not in [0,%d) ", i_ER, qlMPLP_enemyRobot__.size()` not match argument.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I agree with you... but I was receiving a lot of nasty red underlines in QtCreator... =/

And, fact, they are warnings... the macro works nonetheless. But it is annoying, since there are too many of them, and I'll lost more useful warnings.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks!!! 
That solved part of the problem. I was missing a %d in some callings. 
But, I still have some... =/

Comment: You should also show the lines referred by the warnings, what do you think?-/

Comment: As long as the warnings say "to many" instead of "to few" the warnings are merely annoying. Still, should be easy to fix though.

Comment: @alk Done! =]
I'll upload the code to github after it is stable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It also is triggering "unknown conversion type character" warnings... =/

Comment: Consider capturing the preprocessor output for the files that still yield warnings (e.g. `gcc -E` if you're using GCC).  It may be easier to recognize the problems there than in the original source.

Comment: @alk, I did that... no visible changes... 

@John 

Line `MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", x, y, z);` comes out as `fprintf(stderr, ("\n[ERROR][%s:%d( %s )]\n---  " "Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)" "  ---\n\n"), "../trunk/mpl_gridenvironment.h", 253, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, x, y, z);;;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the warnings listed in your edit:

```
unknown conversion type character ‘,’ in format
```

This

```
... "Invalid Position at (%l, %l, %l)", ...
```

should be

```
... "Invalid Position at (%ld, %ld, %ld)", ...
```

You pass `long signed int`. The *conversion specifier* for `signed int` is `d`. When passing `long` prefix it with the *length modifier* `l`.

---

And, although unrelated, but please remove the trailing `;` from the marcos.

Comment: @MarceloSilva: This won't happend to you again, be sure ... ;-)

Comment: I need more ritalin... =/

Anyway, I'm glad that there are people who can pinpoint my stupidity. =P
I was cracking my head for 3 days... and couldn't see this.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the difference between

```
#define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

and

```
#define MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
```

When using without arguments, like

```
MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE("Just a message! Hi!");
```

The first one leads to

```
MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, "Just a message! Hi!", __VA_ARGS__)
```

While the second one leads to

```
MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2(stderr, "Just a message! Hi!", __VA_ARGS__, )
```

Which is wrong. Damn wrong. And just dont compile, because MPL_ERROR_MESSAGE2 wasn't expecting that last comma. Do you know why this happens? Should I post a new question?